# Is there a way to use EditorGUILayout.LabelField in EditorWindow inside GUILayout.Button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Linq;

public class SearchableWindow : EditorWindow
{
    string searchString = "";
    static List<GameObject> gameobjecttest = new List<GameObject>();
    Vector2 scrollPos;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Searching")]
    private static void CreateReplaceWithPrefab()
    {
        const int width = 340;
        const int height = 420;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<SearchableWindow>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(EditorStyles.toolbar);
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        searchString = EditorGUILayout.TextField(searchString, EditorStyles.toolbarTextField);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
        {
            var items = Selection.gameObjects;
            // Do comparison here. For example
            var selected = GetChildrenRecursive(items);
            gameobjecttest.AddRange(selected);
        }

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(300), GUILayout.Height(400));
        foreach (GameObject go in gameobjecttest)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(go.name);
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    private void OnSelectionChange()
    {
        Repaint();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<GameObject> GetChildrenRecursive(GameObject root)
    {
        var output = new List<GameObject>();

        //add the root object itself
        output.Add(root);

        // iterate over direct children
        foreach (Transform child in root.transform)
        {
            // add the children themselves
            output.Add(child.gameObject);

            var childsOfchild = GetChildrenRecursive(child.gameObject);
            output.AddRange(childsOfchild);
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<GameObject> GetChildrenRecursive(IEnumerable<GameObject> rootObjects)
    {
        var output = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (var root in rootObjects)
        {
            output.AddRange(GetChildrenRecursive(root));
        }

        // remove any duplicates that would e.g. appear if you select a parent and its child
        return output.Distinct();
    }
}
```

I want to make that when clicking the button it will make the search and will add once the items to the EditorGUILayout.LabelField but the EditorGUILayout.LabelField need ot be inside the OnGUI if it's inside the if `(GUILayout.Button("Search"))` it will not add the items to the EditorGUILayout.LabelField

Now it keep adding nonstop to the EditorGUILayout.LabelField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear.

If your question is only whether it is possible or not:

**No!** (at least not how you expect it)

anything within this block:

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
{
     ...
}
```

is only executed exactly the moment, the button is actually pressed.

So you have to do it the way you did it already. Maybe adding an additional check for only showing those fields if the list is not empty:

```
// only show the button while the list is empty
if(gameobjecttest.Count == 0)
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
    {
         ...
    }

    // skip the rest
    return;
}

// otherwise show the list
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
{
    scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(300), GUILayout.Height(400));
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in gameobjecttest)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(go.name);
        }
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
}
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

(I usually add those `{` `}` for cleaning up the code a bit)

Or keep the button but disable it instead

```
EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(gameobjecttest.Count != 0);
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
    {
         ...
    }
}
EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
```

Comment: Like in my other question the same problem here. Since the foreach (GameObject go in gameobjecttest) is inside the OnGUI when you drag the window or scroll up/down it's moving very slow and shaking/stuttering since it's doing the foreach loop nonstop. I wonder how they did it in the Hierarchy that it's working so smooth. But I guess there is no solution for this.

Comment: If it were not inside the `OnGUI` you wouldn't see anything ... those are DrawCalls and have to be there. Ofcourse it depends how much objects you are showing there on the same time but maybe the slowness/stuttering doesn't come from the LabelFields themselfes but something lese?

Comment: The slowdown/stuttering is since in my Hierarchy there are more then 5000 gameobjects and childs. If in gameobjects there are only some GameObjects like 5 or 10 it will work smooth but if there are a lot of GameObjects it will move slow stutter.

Comment: Look at this image screenshot for example: https://imgur.com/a/QLtV7Yh You can see there are 13 GameObjects all the same name but not all of them have the same childs. In my scene I have over 5000 objects and searching for each one of them will take time. I wonder why when I filter them it's not showing them with the childs of them like without filtering. The reason Iwant to filter and also see the childs is to check if they all have the same childs or not. But after filtered them it's showing only the parents.

Comment: In the end I created a script that execute also in editor mode that give me the info about the gameobjects with a search button in the inspector: https://pastebin.com/H6MRQkY3 And this is the script for the button: https://pastebin.com/cXtbAfeR That's what I wanted to do in the EditorWindow and that's what I wanted to be in the Hierarchy when filtering objects. Too bad in the inspector you can't make a scroll like in the editorwindow.